# Is Shri Vishnu's Mohini avataram the only avatara where a deity adopts the form of opposition gender?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, gender

Mohini came during samundra manthan to treat devas with amritam.
She also came other times like to kill evil bhasmasura demon.

Is mohini the only avataram which came from opposite gender god?

Or other devas or devis have similar opposite gender avatarams.

Please don't include shiva-shakti ardhanarishwaram or similar forms as they are mixtures of two genders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Devi Purana, An Upa- PurAna of the ShAkta sect, In a certain Kalpa, Devi incarnated in the form of Krishna, And Shiva in the form of Radha.

> **Devi PurAna Chapter 49**

[image]
[image]

Comment: this is a completely new and very very very interesting information ever i heard ever. Thanks for such a new information @user30068

Answer (score 0):

There are many such examples. I am just naming few of them.:

- [Tridevas turned into females when they went to see Mata Bhuvaneshwari.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57137.html)
- [Narada turned into a female.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57253.html)
- [The birth of Vali and Sughriv.](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-41)
- [Arjuna (Nara Avatara) turning into Napunsak due to the curse of Urvashi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33505/20968) and so on.

I hope this clarifies your queries.